# Shmita learning cycle?

Tags: torah-study

I’m wondering if there’s some sort of standardized learning cycle. Similar to the way daf Yomi is designed to be completed every 7.5 years, it seems to me that it would be a good idea if all
Derachim of limud were attached to one unified learning cycle.

Example: concurrently finish the bavli every shmita cycle, finish the tanach 2-3 times every cycle, finish the mishna every cycle,  finish shulchan aruch 2-3 times every shmita cycle.

People would pick which of these areas of study they would want to partake in.

In summary, There seems to be a certain energy that daf Yomi enjoys because everyone’s on the same page. I think it would be interesting if the shmita cycle, can be, or is used to unify all learning.

Comment: "daf Yomi is designed to be completed every 7.5 years" I don't think that's correct. It's designed to have a reasonable and simple unit per day and it takes however long it takes.